# How to apply different conditions to different months in a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date

so I'm trying to apply different conditions that depends on a date, months to be specific. For example, for January replace the data in TEMP that is above 45 but for February that is above 30 and so on. I already did that with the code below, but the problem is that the data from the previous month is replace it with nan.

This is my code:

```
meses = ["01", "02"]

for i in var_vars:
    if i in dataframes2.columns.values:
        for j in range(len(meses)):
            test_prueba_mes = dataframes2[i].loc[dataframes2['fecha'].dt.month == int(meses[j])]
            test_prueba = test_prueba_mes[dataframes2[i]<dataframes.loc[i]["X"+meses[j]+".max"]]
            dataframes2["Prueba " + str(i)] = test_prueba
```

> Output:

```
    dataframes2.tail(5)

 fecha  TEMP_C_Avg  RH_Avg  Prueba TEMP_C_Avg  Prueba RH_Avg
21 2020-01-01 22:00:00        46.0     103                NaN            NaN
22 2020-01-01 23:00:00        29.0     103                NaN            NaN
23 2020-01-02 00:00:00        31.0       3                NaN            NaN
24 2020-01-02 12:00:00        31.0       2                NaN            NaN
25 2020-02-01 10:00:00        29.0       5               29.0            5.0
```

My desired Output is:

> Output:

```
fecha  TEMP_C_Avg  RH_Avg  Prueba TEMP_C_Avg  Prueba RH_Avg
21 2020-01-01 22:00:00        46.0     103                NaN            NaN
22 2020-01-01 23:00:00        29.0     103               29.0            NaN
23 2020-01-02 00:00:00        31.0       3               31.0            3.0
24 2020-01-02 12:00:00        31.0       2               31.0            2.0
25 2020-02-01 10:00:00        29.0       5               29.0            5.0
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me.

Update: The ruleset for 6 months is jan 45, feb 30, mar 45, abr 10, may 15, jun 30

An example of the data:

```
                 fecha  TEMP_C_Avg  RH_Avg
25 2020-02-01 10:00:00        29.0       5
26 2020-02-01 11:00:00        32.0     105
27 2020-03-01 10:00:00        55.0       3
28 2020-03-01 11:00:00        40.0       5
29 2020-04-01 10:00:00        10.0      20
30 2020-04-01 11:00:00         5.0      15
31 2020-05-01 10:00:00        20.0      15
32 2020-05-01 11:00:00         5.0     106
33 2020-06-01 10:00:00        33.0     107
34 2020-06-01 11:00:00        20.0      20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With clear understanding

- have encoded monthly limits into a `dict` **limits**
- use numpy `select()`, when a condition matches take value corresponding to condition from second parameter.  Default to third parameter
- build conditions dynamically from **limits** `dict`
- second parameter needs to be same length as conditions `list`. Build list of `np.nan` as `list` comprehension so it's correct length
- to consider all columns, use a `dict` comprehension that builds `**kwarg` params to `assign()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                 fecha  TEMP_C_Avg  RH_Avg
25  2020-02-01 10:00:00        29.0       5
26  2020-02-01 11:00:00        32.0     105
27  2020-03-01 10:00:00        55.0       3
28  2020-03-01 11:00:00        40.0       5
29  2020-04-01 10:00:00        10.0      20
30  2020-04-01 11:00:00         5.0      15
31  2020-05-01 10:00:00        20.0      15
32  2020-05-01 11:00:00         5.0     106
33  2020-06-01 10:00:00        33.0     107
34  2020-06-01 11:00:00        20.0      20"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df.fecha = pd.to_datetime(df.fecha)

# The ruleset for 6 months is jan 45, feb 30, mar 45, abr 10, may 15, jun 30
limits = {1:45, 2:30, 3:45, 4:10, 5:15, 6:30}

df = df.assign(**{f"Prueba {c}":np.select( # construct target column name
        # build a condition for each of the month limits
        [df.fecha.dt.month.eq(m) & df[c].gt(l) for m,l in limits.items()], 
        [np.nan for m in limits.keys()], # NaN if beyond limit
        df[c]) # keep value if within limits
            for c in df.columns if "Avg" in c}) # do calc for all columns that have "Avg" in name
```

|  | fecha | TEMP_C_Avg | RH_Avg | Prueba TEMP_C_Avg | Prueba RH_Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 2020-02-01 10:00:00 | 29 | 5 | 29 | 5 |
| 26 | 2020-02-01 11:00:00 | 32 | 105 | nan | nan |
| 27 | 2020-03-01 10:00:00 | 55 | 3 | nan | 3 |
| 28 | 2020-03-01 11:00:00 | 40 | 5 | 40 | 5 |
| 29 | 2020-04-01 10:00:00 | 10 | 20 | 10 | nan |
| 30 | 2020-04-01 11:00:00 | 5 | 15 | 5 | nan |
| 31 | 2020-05-01 10:00:00 | 20 | 15 | nan | 15 |
| 32 | 2020-05-01 11:00:00 | 5 | 106 | 5 | nan |
| 33 | 2020-06-01 10:00:00 | 33 | 107 | nan | nan |
| 34 | 2020-06-01 11:00:00 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |

Comment: Thanks, Rob. It works, but not quite for what I'm trying to do, your code and mine at some point do the same. The problem is, that it is not just JAN and FEB, is all the months, thats why I did a for loop, but when I'm trying to loop over the months it doesn't work. In my code, replace all the values from the previous month with nan, and in yours do nothing with the previous month.

Comment: you can build the conditions list as a comprehesion to cover all months.  if you provide the ruleset for all 12 months I'll update answer.  I only know the limits you wrote for Jan & Feb

Comment: Rob, I just updated the question with the ruleset for the first 6 months, I think that will work.

Comment: The ruleset for 6 months is jan 45, feb 30, mar 45, abr 10, may 15, jun 30

Comment: now you have set out source data and requirements clearly I've adapted.  It is a fully vectorised solution so should perform well